# How do I look up for a particular value in an Access Form record, and if not found, add a new record with that value?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been looking for a solution in many different places, but have not been able to find a clean answer.

I need my Access program to look up for a particular value, based on entry in a text box, if found, go to that record (easy part), and if not, add a new record for that particular value being assigned to the respective field.

```
Private Sub myTextBox_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
dim actNo as String

Set db = CurrentDb
actNo = Me.AccountNumber

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="myClients", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)

With rs
    .FindFirst "AccountNumber = '" & actNo & "'"
    If Not .NoMatch Then
        Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
    Else  
 ' This is where it gets tricky.  Tried many of the variations below, none 
 ' works.
    .AddNew
    !AccountNumber= actNo
    .Update
    Me.Refresh

    ' Neither something like:
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
    End If
End With

Cleanup:
rs.Close
db.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean this? `rs!AccountNumber = actNo` Also, you are missing an `End If`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you add a new record to your recordset:

```
.AddNew
rs!AccountNumber = actNo
.Update
```

Alternatively:

```
.AddNew
.Fields("AccountNumber") = actNo
.Update
```

Comment: I have done that (right after Else).  But the form does not refresh (in spite of Me.Refresh).  Every other field keeps showing the data from the last record.

Comment: @Kambiz Try `Me.Requery`

Comment: Did nt help much, even though I remembered I used Requery with success in the past.  It creates a new record with the new AccountNumber, but it also change the AccountNumber of the record that the form was showing too!
Also, I get the error of "Update or CancelUpdate without AddNew or Edit" frequently.

Comment: My best bet would be that you cannot use `!` with `With`. Try `rs!AccountNumber` as the proposed answer actually suggest and unlike what you have actually done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *RecordsetClone*:

```
Private Sub myTextBox_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim actNo As String

    actNo = Me!AccountNumber.Value

    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

    With rs
        .FindFirst "AccountNumber = '" & actNo & "'"
        If .NoMatch Then
            .AddNew
                !AccountNumber.Value = actNo
            .Update
        End If
        Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
    End With

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```